# Scapy - How can I hide the report of sendp\sr1 and just get the final?‏

Tags: python, scapy, packets

I am working with scapy and I started to learn how to build packets (if someone has a good example on the internet to learn from it - it will be great! thanks.).

I have the next command in scapy:

```
srp(Ether(dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff')/ARP(pdst=ip)/Padding(load='\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'),timeout=2)
```

Which send an arp packet in layer 2.
When I do this command, its giving me the next answer:

> WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
>   Begin emission:
>   *Finished to send 1 packets.
>
> Received 1 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 0 packets
>
> 00:50:56:e9:b8:b1

for the next code:

```
def Arp_Req(ip):
        packet = srp(Ether(dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff')/ARP(pdst=ip)/Padding(load='\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'),timeout=2)
        try:
                packet[0][0]
                return packet[0][0][1].hwsrc
        except IndexError:
                return "(E2)CANT FIND AN ANSWER FOR "+ip+"."
```

I want to hide all the report and print just the return answer. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the output here come from a warning, due to IPv6, which you may avoid by disabling IPv6 support (from scapy), but you also have output generated by the function `srp()` itself, and for that you need to set the `verbose` argument:

```
from scapy.config import conf  
conf.ipv6_enabled = False
from scapy.all import *

def Arp_Req(ip):
    packet = srp(Ether(dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff')/ARP(pdst=ip)/Padding(load='\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'),timeout=2, verbose=0)
    try:
        packet[0][0]
        return packet[0][0][1].hwsrc
    except IndexError:
        return "(E2)CANT FIND AN ANSWER FOR "+ip+"."

# example
print Arp_Req("192.168.0.254")
```